# Change the focus from one Text widget to another

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a simple GUI using Tkinter.

So often in many user interfaces, hitting the tab button will change the focus from one Text widget to another. Whenever I'm in a Text widget, tab only indents the text cursor.

Does anyone know if this is configurable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is very easy to do with Tkinter.

There are a couple of things that have to happen to make this work. First, you need to make sure that the standard behavior *doesn't* happen. That is, you don't want tab to both insert a tab and move focus to the next widget. By default events are processed by a specific widget prior to where the standard behavior occurs (typically in class bindings). Tk has a simple built-in mechanism to stop events from further processing.

Second, you need to make sure you send focus to the appropriate widget. There is built-in support for determining what the next widget is.

For example:

```
def focus_next_window(event):
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
    return("break")

text_widget=Text(...)
text_widget.bind("<Tab>", focus_next_window)
```

Important points about this code:

- The method `tk_focusNext()` returns the next widget in the keyboard traversal hierarchy.
- the method `focus()` sets the focus to that widget
- returning `"break"` is critical in that it prevents the class binding from firing. It is this class binding that inserts the tab character, which you don't want.

If you want this behavior for all text widgets in an application you can use the `bind_class()` method instead of `bind()` to make this binding affect all text widgets.

You can also have the binding send focus to a very specific widget but I recommend sticking with the default traversal order, then make sure the traversal order is correct.

Comment: I had a mostly unrelated question about how to make some extra steps happen in response to a <Tab>, **without** actually stopping the <Tab> from carrying out its default behavior.  This answer covered it perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

The focus traversal is somewhat customizable, usually letting the X windows manager handle it (with focus follows mouse, or click). According to [the manual](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/) it should be possible to [`bind`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm) an event to the key press event, for tab presses, and triggering a [`focusNext`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/focusNext.htm) event in those cases.

Comment: I don't get it; I suggested exactly what http://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley wrote in his accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450180/how-can-i-change-the-focus-from-one-text-box-to-another-in-python-tkinter/1451343#1451343 didn't I?

Comment: Your answer is too weak to be useful. I don't think it's true that focus traversal is customizable "due to the cross platform nature". Being cross-platform has nothing to do with it. Further, your answer says "it _should_ be possible". If I'm looking for help and someone says "it should be possible" I don't find that very reassuring. Either it is or it isn't. And finally "scanning for tab presses" makes no sense -- there's no way to "[scan] for tab presses" and you don't say how to do it. It sounds like your answer is a guess, which makes it less useful.

Answer (score -5):

It is really simple in PyQt4 simply use this one single line below and you will be able to change focus by pressing tab button:

self.textEdit.setTabChangesFocus(True)

Comment: A PyQt4 solution is useless for someone using Tkinter.