# How Transfer cursor in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i wrote bellow code in python 3.6.2 by tkinter,I want the cursor move to password textbox  when user press Enter key in username textbox.

```
from tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_main()
    def create_main(self):
        print("testing")
        self.title = Label(self, text=" Stuck In The Circle ")
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.user_entry_label = Label(self, text="Username: ")
        self.user_entry_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.user_entry = Entry(self)                        
        self.user_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.pass_entry_label = Label(self, text="Password: ")
        self.pass_entry_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.pass_entry = Entry(self)                        
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.user_entry = Entry(self, justify="right")   
        self.pass_entry = Entry(self, justify="right")
        self.sign_in_butt = Button(self, text="Sign In",command = self.logging_in)#SIGN IN BUTTON
        self.sign_in_butt.grid(row=5, column=2)
    def logging_in(self):
     user_get = self.user_entry.get()
     pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()
root = Tk()
root.title("Stuck in the Circle")
root.geometry("400x100")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can do it?

Comment: Try the technique used [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704032/how-can-i-set-the-mouse-position-in-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a lot simpler than I expected it to be.

We can use `.bind()` to get a callback on the `<Return>` event. This means that every time the return character is pressed whenever the defined widget is in focus we get a callback.

In order to get it to cycle to the next widget we can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451343/4528269) from Bryan Oakley:

> ```
> def focus_next_window(event):
> event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
> return("break")
>
> text_widget=Text(...) text_widget.bind("<Tab>", focus_next_window)
> ```
>
> Important points about this code:
>
> The method tk_focusNext() returns the next widget in the keyboard
>   traversal hierarchy. the method focus() sets the focus to that widget
>   returning "break" is critical in that it prevents the class binding
>   from firing. It is this class binding that inserts the tab character,
>   which you don't want.

So, applying the same logic in our situation we can use something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", self.callback)
    def callback(self, event):
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```